# subscript doesnot work in set function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to use SL as a subscript.
Why it doesn't work with set function? how should I write the code?

```
w=figure;
Labels={'E-O_{SL}','R','E','S','O','P','Sw','Lu'};
x=[1:8];
y=[0.81 0.78 0.79 0.92 0.81 0.46 0.89 0.86];
bar(x,y,'FaceColor',[0.360 0.50 0],'BarWidth',0.8);
set(gca,'xticklabel',Labels,'FontSize',8);
ylabel('Precision','FontSize',11);
set(w, 'Position', [0 0 800, 800]);
ylim([0 1]);
```

Thanks

Comment: It works fine in MATLAB R2017a. I can give your the plot if you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is what you want, your code works just fine in MATLAB 2015b.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. so it should work with 2016b. I'm going to install 2016b, the only version I have!!

Comment: So you asked the question before having MATLAB installed?

Comment: I have old version actually!